# How do I get the index of my environment object array in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am struggling to get the index of the object I am using in the for each loop. I am trying to add a delete button next to each item in the array that removes the item from the object array. So I would have a button inside the for each loop, and remove the item at that index.

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

```
import SwiftUI

struct AddedFoods:Identifiable{
    var name: String = ""
    var totalCals: Double = 0
    var totalProtein: Double = 0
    var totalCarbs: Double = 0
    var totalFat: Double = 0
    var id = UUID().uuidString
   //Your other properties
}


class FoodAddModel: ObservableObject,Identifiable {
    
    @Published var foods : [AddedFoods]?
    
    var id = UUID().uuidString

    init() {
        dummyData()
    }
    
    func dummyData() {
        var obj:[AddedFoods] = []
        obj.append(AddedFoods(name: "Pasta", totalCals: 340, totalProtein: 20, totalCarbs: 45, totalFat: 15))
        obj.append(AddedFoods(name: "Chicken", totalCals: 560, totalProtein: 20, totalCarbs: 45, totalFat: 15))
        obj.append(AddedFoods(name: "Apple", totalCals: 54, totalProtein: 20, totalCarbs: 45, totalFat: 15))
        obj.append(AddedFoods(name: "Noodles", totalCals: 231, totalProtein: 20, totalCarbs: 45, totalFat: 15))
        foods = obj
    }
}

struct myView:View{
    @EnvironmentObject var getFood:FoodAddModel
    @EnvironmentObject var person: UserInfoModel


    var unwrappedFoods:[AddedFoods]{
        getFood.foods ?? []
    }
    
    var body: some View{
        NavigationView{
            
        List{
        ForEach(unwrappedFoods) {obj in
            let b: String = String(obj.totalCals)
            
            List{
                HStack{
                        Text(obj.name)
                        Text(b)
                }
            }
        }.onDelete(perform: { indexSet in
            /*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*//*@PLACEHOLDER=Code@*/ /*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/
        })

        }
    }
    }
    }
```

Comment: Hi Matthew -- I see you're using my solution in a separate question you've asked. If my solution is working for you, would you mind accepting my answer (the green checkmark). Looking at your profile I see it looks like you've never accepted an answer to one of your questions.

Answer (score 1):

My favorite pattern for this is using `enumerated()`. If you were doing this with a huge list, you may want to do some performance testing to see if it's doing extra work as opposed to just doing the for loop on the indexes, but for my purposes, it's worked pretty well:

```
ForEach(Array(unwrappedFoods.enumerated()), id: \.1.id) { (index, obj) in
            HStack {
                Text(obj.name)
                Spacer()
                Button(action: {
                    //delete with index
                }) {
                    Text("Delete")
                }
            }
        }
```

`obj` gives you the `AddedFoods`, just as before and `index` is (obviously) the index.

`id` has to use `.1.id` because `.1` is now the second part of the tuple (in your case, the `AddedFoods`).